# Xcode9-beta2 destroyed my project/compiler/environment

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta, xcode9

My project works fine in Xcode 8.3.3. When I compile my project with Xcode 9, it shows compile error in some C++ files which have been included into my project for a long time. Then I switch to Xcode 8.3.3 and just want it built successfully, however, Xcode keeps on showing the previous error in Xcode 9.

Clean project/delete derived data/relaunch Xcode/reboot/uninstall Xcode9 and reinstall Xcode 8.3.3, all of them don't work. I think some of configurations are destroyed by Xcode9-beta2.

Anyone could help.

Comment: It is beta software. You can expect problems. Restore your project from a backup or source code control.

Comment: I have hard reset my project, not work.. @Paulw11

Comment: Then you need to provide some more details on the errors you are seeing. Have you made sure that you are using the Xcode 8.3 command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. After repeating those attempts, it now works. I don't know why, maybe it just got stuck. Anyway, thank you for your help. @Paulw11